# Save a data collection into a text file

Tags: c#, datagridview, save, addressbook

I am new to developing and I am creating an AddressBook using c#.

I am trying to save my data collection using my DataLayer class into a txt file. The data collection is displayed in a DataGridView which is located in my AddressBook GUI

I would like to save the data collection without touching the DataGridView.

What would be the best way to do this, and could I have an example please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx

Comment: just consider each address is a line in a text file. Then iterate over your list and write the data in the format you want. Just follows the tons of examples of file manipulation on the net

Answer (score 0):

Here AddressBook is array of string.
You can write full array using the below give method of File class.

```
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Addresses.txt", AddressBook);
```